# cant connect to oracle - ora-01017

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-01017

i installed Oracle 11.2.0 64bit & Oracle SQL developer 2.1.1.64 on Windows-7 64bit

i try to connect to database like this:

```
username: scott
password: tiger
role    : sysdba
hostname: localhost
port    : 1521
sid     : ORCL
```

and i got this error: `ora-01017 invalid username/password; logon denied`

what can be the problem ?  what to check ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

11g allows for case-sensitive passwords, so firstly check the password TIGER (and maybe Tiger)

Answer (score 2):

since the database is on your local machine, easiest is to connect to it using os authentication and reset the password to a known value and then use that to connect using the tool you want. On windows you can do this in the *nix style. First find where your oracle rdbms installation is located and assign that value to the ORACLE_HOME environment variable. Use the commandline tool.

```
ORACLE_HOME=d:\somwehere\on\your\disk
PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
alter user scott identified by koffie;
```

(make sure you remember the password this time, including case as since 11g passwords are case sensitive.) sqlplus should be in %ORACLE_HOME%\bin. Check this before.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Is the account unlocked? As a privileged (SYS account) try running:

```
 SELECT USERNAME, ACCOUNT_STATUS
 FROM DBA_USERS
 WHERE USERNAME = 'SCOTT';
```

If the account is locked, try:

```
ALTER USER SCOTT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Also it appears you are trying to connect to the database as SYSDBA using the SCOTT account.  I believe by default this schema lacks the necessary account privileges.  Try logging in as SCOTT/TIGER connecting as "normal", not "sysdba".

-CJ

Comment: thanks for the help !  where to run this query ? i cant open any oracle editor

Comment: Try the sqlplus command line utility.  Located in $ORACLE_HOME/bin directory on your server.  $ sqlplus / as sysdba  - Once logged in, try running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
orapwd file=$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapw$ORACLE_SID password=Euro2016 entries=5
grant sysdba to scott;

Now you can connect...